# Completion Status of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, monitoring

I was wondering if this is possible or not,

If a query is taking so much time, can i see the percentage of query left or done?
 any where in system ?

I know its a silly question but sometime one get annoyed waiting for query to complete with out know how much more time will it take.

Comment: have you tried `execution plan` and `Client statistics` ? However i don't think you can check query in the middle of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some requests do have a percent complete estimate, and it can be viewed in [`sys.dm_exec_requests.percent_complete`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx):

> Percentage of work completed for the following commands:
>
> - ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE
> - AUTO_SHRINK option with ALTER DATABASE
> - BACKUP DATABASE
> - DBCC CHECKDB
> - DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP
> - DBCC CHECKTABLE
> - DBCC INDEXDEFRAG
> - DBCC SHRINKDATABASE
> - DBCC SHRINKFILE
> - RECOVERY
> - RESTORE DATABASE,
> - ROLLBACK
> - TDE ENCRYPTION
>
> Is not nullable.

But you're probably interested in query requests (`SELECT`). In such case, if they take so much time as to start wondering what the heck are they doing, it is called you have a performance problem at your hand. Approach it as a performance investigation. Use a methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) to identify the bottlenecks. Address the discovered bottlenecks.

Comment: Can we do some sort of monitoring in SP's ?

Comment: @AshutoshArya: [`sp_who_is_active`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to know how much longer a query will take because the database engine does not "know" how much total time is needed to complete the query.  Depending on the logic of your query the engine will be scanning/seeking on various tables and indexes and selecting which rows satisfy your criteria.

Once the engine has logically worked its way through your query and selected all the valid rows, it is "done".

This is much different than a file copy for example, where the file system knows it has X megabytes to read/write.

The best practical way to get the information you are looking for is probably to record the execution times of similar (by tables, joins, filters) queries and in the past and use that as an estimate for the current one.